# How can I read streaming data from a camera connected to I2C on Linux?

Tags: linux, i2c

I've looked for ways of reading camera data connected to I2C on Linux.

What is the normal way to achieve the goal?

Could you please show me a skeleton code or running code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a userspace program to talk to the `i2c-driver`. There are some `SMbus` functions defined to do the data read/write from the userspace to the device driver.

Read here for more: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface